# Resharper InspectCode with multiple ReferencePaths

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm trying to run inspectcode.exe from console providing a solution that requires multiple assembly-reference paths

As some Reference-Paths are missing I used the --properties param to supply those.
Unfortunately it seems that this is not working due to : and ; in my parameter.

```
r:\solution> d:\InspectCode\inspectcode.exe --output=InspectCodeReport.xml "MainSolution.sln"  --properties:ReferencePath="r:\reference1\;r:\reference2\"
```

The error-message received is:

```
The name "r:\reference2" contains an invalid character ":".
```

So there must clearly be a problem with the : in the path r:\

- Providing relative paths (....\referenceA) didn't work either
- Escaping with %3A (for :) and %3B (for ;) didn't work

Any idea how to provide multiple reference paths?

If this doesn't work I'm going for a workaround of copying all assembly-references to one spesific folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, a semicolon can't be used as a separator inside values. I filed [a new request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-476901), so you can track the status.